# Is it possible to hide/disable print and save button for 1 specific report and not all the reports on SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2014

Done some research and there's a option in server properties to set  Enable Client Printing to false. But is there a way to disable it for 1 specific report?

Comment: No, I do not think this is possible.. it's either all or nothing.. unfortunately.

Comment: You will have to hack html of report viewer, I did that once it is ugly and unsupported. Would not recommend.

Comment: Thanks for the response